# Change the URL in Vue 3 on onBeforeMouted()?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vue-router, vue-composition-api

I'm currently working on a social media in Vue 3.

I have a feed page which display all the posts and there's a comments section for each post. For each comment, there's the author's name and the content of the comment.
In the case of my project, the author's name is a router link in this format:

`` <router-link :to="`user/${userId}`"> John Doe </router-link> ``

Basically, by clicking on the name, I go to the user's profile page. However, I'd like the URL to change to **/user/nickname** rather than **/user/userId** when I get to the page because a big bunch of numbers doesn't look nice. I wanted to do a getUser(id) API call (because I have the ID thanks to params) that returns the user nickname on onBeforeMounted() function but idk what to do after that.

Thanks in advance for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
   <template>
      <div class="hello">
        <router-link :to="`user/${getName(1)}`"> John Doe </router-link>
      </div>
    </template>

 <script setup>
 const getName = async (id) => {
    let name = await getApiName(id)

  return name;
 };
 </script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response ! But what shoud I do if a user directly /user/${nickame} on the search bar without clicking the name in comment. Then there'll be no id D:

Comment: How the template looks is not related to how the routes are managed. If the user enters data directly in the url, if you did the /user/:id route correctly, everything should work.  The documentation https://v3.router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-routes.html